# How can I make two graphic cards NVIDIA work at same time with 4 screens?

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

I have 2 graphic cards NVIDIA: Nvidia GT730 2GB, Nvidia NVS300 with 256kb.

```
blue@blue-S5500BC:/var/log$ lspci|grep -i vga
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300] (rev a2)
```

I am using XUbuntu 20.04 with xfce. I use my pc mainly to develop software, so I don't really care about 3D acceleration, I don't do gaming and I don't need such as 3D performance, but the problem is that I have very very bad performance.

It seems that the secondary video card that I have, the NVIDIA NVS300, only works with NVIDIA drivers ver 340, which seems to be incompatible with the kernel 5.4.0-42.

If I install the nvidia proprietary drivers 440 then it's compatible with the GT730, but it doesn't work with the other graphic card NVS300: according to the logs, the NVS300 is not supported by the proprietary drivers 440.

I have switched to the nouveau drivers and the system works but it has very bad performance, it's unusable and very sloppy.

During the live USB installation, the system detects the 4 screens and it's quite usable but then once I installed the OS in a new partition it has very bad performance.

The question is: what do you guys advise?
Is it possible to install two nvidia drivers at the same time? ver 340 for the NVS300 and the 440 for the GT730? As I don't need such as 3D acceleration, how could I find out why the nouveau drivers are so bad in performance?
Please give me some advice as I need to start a project and using Windows 10 for me is not an option.

Comment: Not an expert on this, but I assume running two different versions of the same Nvidia driver may be at the very least tricky (requiring self-written configs in `Xorg.conf` and such), if not impossible. It's interesting that it appears to work during a USB live session: In that case, I would try to find out which driver is used there (probably the nouveau driver?), which version, and how it is configured. Another straightforward solution would be to get an additional GT370 card to replace the NVS300 card.

Comment: Hello Malte, thanks a lot for your reply.
I have installed the nouveau drivers, version 1:1.0.16-1 amd64
I will search in the documentation to see how works nouveau configuration and if any logs are available

again, thanks for your help

<br/>

blue@blue-S5500BC:~$ apt list|grep nouveau

libdrm-nouveau2/focal,now 2.4.101-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm-nouveau2/focal 2.4.101-2 i386
nouveau-firmware/focal,focal 20091212-0ubuntu1 all
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/focal,now 1:1.0.16-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: Hello Malte, again thanks a lot for your support and your precious time. I have reinstalled the OS with Xubuntu 16.04 and it works very good, using NOUVEAU version 1:1:0:12, no glitches and the performance is PERFECT. At the end of the day you are right, the best solution would be to install another GT730 card as the NVS300 is quite old and it's not supported by the new kernel 5.
As temporary solution I don't mind to use the release 16.04 as it works very good with 4 screens and it works like a charm.
If you don't mind I will mark this question as "problem resolved".

Comment: I'm happy if this helped! I don't think you can mark the question as such as "resolved"; the only thing you can do in that spirit is to accept an answer (if there is one). I converted my previous comment to an answer. If you feel that this helps, you're welcome to accept that answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my original comment to an answer since it appears to have helped (and adding a few more details).

You asked for advice on how to proceed; I see a few possible approaches to your problem.

#### 1. Run two different versions of the Nvidia drivers simultaneously

I am no expert here, but my feeling is that this would be tricky at the least (requiring self-written configs in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and such to invoke the right driver for the right devices), if not impossible (there may be conflicts between these two drivers behind the scenes that are unsolvable without modifying the drivers' sources, and the Nvidia drivers are closed source).

Given that the older version of the driver (version 340) does not run with newer kernels anyway, and you likely don't want to be stuck with an old kernel in the long run, this approach seems to be not only very complicated, but also not very future-oriented. I would not try to explore this unless I have absolutely no other option.

#### 2. Get the Nouveau drivers to run smoothly

Since you said that your four screens are running smoothly on a live system (from a USB stick), and the live system uses the open source Nouveau drivers, it appears that it is at least *possible* to make the Nouveau drivers run smoothly, even though they do not run smoothly on your installed system.

I would thus investigate the differences between the live system and the installed system:

- Which version of the Nouveau drivers do these two systems use?
- Are there configuration differences between the used drivers, e.g., in `Xorg.conf` (cf. https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiMonitorDesktop)?
- Which kernel versions are these two systems runnning?
- Can you find any relevant differences in the log messages (e.g., `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`)?
- etc.

Reducing those differences may very well lead you to the solution.

#### 3. Use the same graphic cards

I want to mention this for the purpose of completeness: You have one GT730 and one NVS300 card. It may be worth considering to replace your old NVS300 card with an additional GT370 card. That way, you will have two GT370 cards, which will be inherently less error-prone. While this approach costs a bit of money, it very probably costs the least amount of time. It's up to you to decide which you prefer. ;-)